# how to retrieve the particular row in android from database

Tags: sqlite

I am developing the bmi calculator app, in this app i stored the details of the person into the sqlite database.. but the problem is when i am trying to get the record of the any person using the search button .. in the activity..
Help me to correct the code in the activity

in the database i used the following code..

```
public Cursor getContact(String candidate) throws SQLException

{

    //db.
Cursor  mCursor =db.query(true,TABLE_NAME,new String[]{CANDIDATE_NAME,CANDIDATE_FATHER,CANDIDATE_HEIGHT,CANDIDATE_WEIGHT,CANDIDATE_BMI},CANDIDATE_NAME+"=?", null, null, null, null, null);

if (mCursor != null) {
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
   }
return mCursor;
}   
}
```

In activity to retrieve the record i used following code..

```
try{
dbadapter.open();
EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
st=et.getEditableText().toString();
//int n=Integer.parseInt(st);
Cursor c=dbadapter.getContact(st);

    //c.moveToFirst();
//TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Name : "+c.getString(0)+"\n" +"Father's Name : "+c.getString(1)+"\n"+"Height : "+c.getString(2)+"\n"+"Weight : "+c.getString(3)+"\n"+"BMI : "+c.getString(4),5000).show();
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "searching", 5000).show();


dbadapter.close();
```

the above code in the activity is not working pl have a time in this to correct the code and thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing the arguments for the sqlite query.
On the line:

`Cursor  mCursor =db.query(true,TABLE_NAME,new String[]{CANDIDATE_NAME,CANDIDATE_FATHER,CANDIDATE_HEIGHT,CANDIDATE_WEIGHT,CANDIDATE_BMI},CANDIDATE_NAME+"=?", null, null, null, null, null);`

replace the first `null` by `new String[]{candidate)` if the method parameter `candidate` is your candidate name.